# how to enable xss requests only for google gadgets

Tags: gmail, google-gadget

I'm building a google gadget application that needs to interact with my server.  However, I need to enable cross-domain requests on my scripts to allow for this:

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

I'd like to only open up requests originating from Google but setting the following value does not work:
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: google.com');

What should I be setting to make this work for google gadgets?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer here is 'gmodules.com', based on the 'origin' header that I caught in the firebug console.